# Clojure enlive: the function html-content can't operate a function with an argument (?)

Tags: html, clojure, enlive

So i made a simple html template using deftemplate,

```
(html/deftemplate header "selmer/header.html"
  [])    

(html/deftemplate footer "selmer/footer.html"
  [])

(html/deftemplate blogp "selmer/blogpage.html"
  [id]
  [:bjudul] (html/content (:title (db/finddata id)))
  [:bisi] (html/content (:content (db/finddata id))))
```

(Note:        `db/finddata id`        is a function that takes a number as a **data Id** and returns a map of data from my database by a certain **data id**, 
for example if i type

```
(db/finddata 1)
```

it will produce this

```
{:title "Wowtitle", :content "wowcontent", :id 1}
```

it is a data from my database with an **id of 1**)

and then

```
(html/deftemplate layout "selmer/layout.html"
  [content contenttitle]
  [:title] (html/content contenttitle)
  [:header] (html/html-content (apply str (header)))
  [:pagecontents] (html/html-content (apply str (content)))
  [:footer] (html/html-content (apply str (footer))))

(defn createpage [pcontents tcontent]
  (apply str (layout pcontents tcontent)))
```

but when i type this in repl

```
(createpage (blogp id) "Blog")
```

it produces this error

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  zenblog.pageandctrl.pagelayout/fn--14851/fn--14853/fn--14854 (form-init2686073120612682758.clj:1)
```

it seems worked just fine with another deftemplate, for example if i change the blogp code

```
(html/deftemplate blogp "selmer/blogpage.html"
  []
  [:bjudul] (html/content (:Judul (db/findById **1**)))
  [:bisi] (html/content (:Isi (db/findById **1**))))
```

and then i typed this in repl

```
(createpage blogp "Blog")
```

it worked just fine. Any ideas why?

im new to clojure and im new to enlive as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `layout` template expect the `content` param to be a function whereas when you do `(blogp id)` you are actually passing the result of the function and not the function itself. What you can do is use it like this:

```
(createpage (partial blogp id) "Blog")
```